# Does lightning components load asynchronously?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

If I have 5 different lightning components in my lightning page, how do they load? Are they all loading at the same time, asynchronsouly?

Is there a way to control which loads first, second, third, etc...?

Thanks

Comment: What's your actual question, though? Why do you need to control the order of loading? Please read about what an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) is, then [edit] your question to include your use case, any problems you're experiencing, etc.

Comment: The question is basically, how does the lightning components load on the page? Do they load all at the same time when the page loads, does it load chronologically? Just a straight forward question, sorry if it doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm), the general idea is that the app container is loaded first, parent components are loaded next, then child components are recursively loaded back up to the parent components. As far as initialization goes, children are initialized before their parents, but after attribute propagation. Aside from ordering your source code, there's no way to control markup-generated component initialization. If you want to control the order better, you could use $A.createComponents to encourage a specific load order, but this has performance implications. Also note that aura:if renders asynchronously as well, so using aura:if can result in other components loading out of order.